# Route drawn using CGContextStrokePath rotates as the heading rotates

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit

I have created a maps application which can draw a route between two locations.  Let's say the user's location and the destination.

In order to show the user the direction of the destination, in relation to their position, I implement:

```
setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading
```

The route is drawn using `CGContextStrokePath` and the path is stroked in a `UIImageView`.

I refresh the path each time `regionDidChangeAnimated` is called.  But until it is called, the route rotates with the "heading lamp" (if you know what I mean)?

Therefore, as I try to point the phone towards a destination, the map rotates, and so does the route I have just stroked.  Until the user touches the screen and the path is redrawn.

My question is:
How can I stop the route I have drawn from turning with the heading lamp?

Comment: Is the UIImageView inside an MKOverlayView?  If not, how is it shown?  Can you show some of the code in regionDidChangeAnimated?

Comment: Hey Anna.. I have created a routeView(UIImageView), which is a subView of the mapView i use to display the map. (Nothing to do with MKOverlay.) When I call "regionDidChangeAnimated", i update the routeView which allows for zooming..This means the route disappears when the map is zoomed, and redraws the route when zooming is finished..which works fine.. The only thing is, if i want to show heading, and start tracking for heading, i get this problem of the route moving, only until i re-zoom.. if you know what i mean?

Comment: Thanks Anna.. You made me re-think the way i was approaching the problem.. Got rid of imageView and used MKOverlay with MKPolyline.. displays perfectly.. Problem solved! Your a legend!